# TCP/UDP multiplexing-demultiplexing

Tags: networking

I was going through this topic and read that TCP uses 4 identifiers for multiplexing-demultiplexing (source IP, source port number, destination IP, destination port number) whereas UDP uses 2 identifiers( destination IP, destination port number)

Is there a reason for that or the protocol is designed in that way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How TCP/UDP demultiplexing works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960238/how-tcp-udp-demultiplexing-works)

Comment: Shortly, because TCP is a connection-oriented protocol, whereas UDP is connection*less*. TCP needs more information to keep track of its connection state semantics, so it makes sense intuitively that TCP uses more identifiers.

Comment: yaa i got the point that TCP needs more info... but why that is needed at the demultiplexing level? The additional info is there in TCP header

Answer (score 3):

In TCP, connections persist between packets, so the destination machine needs to keep
track of which packets belong to which connection.  UDP packets are one-off events, so that sort of bookkeeping isn't required.

Comment: but couldn't that be done at a later stage, say after demultiplexing, the applications that are listening to that port, decide which process it belongs to?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of having the TCP layer manage the persistent connections.