# Demultiplexing in TCP/UDP

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I know there is an older answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960238/how-tcp-udp-demultiplexing-works), though it does not seem to answer my question. If in UDP two people with different IP and different ports send data to the same server (same IP) at the same socket (since in UDP there is only one socket per application - correct me if i am wrong), how does server recognises which person is who? 
Does it change anything if the two people use (by luck or not) the same port as source port but with different source IP?

Comment: The source address is returned by `recvfrom()`. It consists of an IP address and a port number. There is no ambiguity if one of these is the same across two clients. They can't both be the same, by definition.

Comment: @EJP Ok and they are both server by the same socket, am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server can receive UDP datagrams from two different IP/port pairs (IP could be same, port could be same, or both could be different) on the same port.  The `recvfrom()` function returns the source IP/port of the datagram in addition to the data.

As mentioned in the question you referenced, a UDP socket is defined only by the local IP and local port.  The remote IP and port can differ for both outgoing and incoming packets.

Comment: Ok so if two people send to the server on the same port and they have different IP and ports they will both get served by the same UDP socket correct?

Comment: Correct.  The server will know where the packet came from based on the extra data returned by `recvfrom()`

Comment: This might be a bit trivial, but when you say extra data can you be more specific?

Comment: `ssize_t recvfrom(int s, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *from, socklen_t *fromlen);`  The IP/port of the message sender is returned in the `from` parameter.

Comment: So the server will know whci person is who with the **from** parameter which contains the ip/port of the message center, correct?